# How to find the lost mobile when no tracker app is installed?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, lost-phone

3 weeks ago, I lost my Samsung Galaxy Ace Dduos 6082.

I don't have any tracker applications or any "if lost" applications installed. I'm looking for some tracker. I have IMEI number and Gmail installed in that.

Is there any way to find my lost Samsung Galaxy Ace S6082?

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of [plan b](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb) ?

> Plan B is your last resort to find your missing phone. This is the
>   first and only 'find my phone' app that you download AFTER you've
>   already lost your phone. Having Lookout on your phone is the best way
>   to protect your phone and find it fast, but use Plan B if you have
>   already lost your phone and didn't have Lookout installed.

```
================= 
NOTE: Plan B only works with 2.0 - 2.3 versions of Android
=================
```

Comment: And so is [AndroidLost](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidlost&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hbmRyb2lkbG9zdCJd) as long as you are sure that the lost phone still uses your GMail account.